# Gradle Project Sync Failed - Android Studio - Failed to find Build Tools revision 27.1.0

Tags: android, gradle

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.sqliteapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- core:3.0.2'
}
```

Error occurred

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Failed to find Build Tools revision 27.1.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 2s
Failed to find Build Tools revision 27.1.0

build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code to your build.gradle (app Level)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }

    }
```

}